# JQuery function acting strangely with animation

Tags: jquery

I'm writing a couple fairly simple functions. Essentially, I have a navigation bar with several links. When clicked, each link shows a div that was previously on display:none. When a link is clicked I want the navigation bar to shrink and move up. This is working but there seems to be a bit of a problem.

I have two classes that contain the css for the navigation bar. "Before" is the class that has the css for the navigation bar before a link is clicked. "After" is for after a link is clicked and causes the navigation bar to get smaller and move up. I have similar classes for the links in the navigation bar.

The problem comes in when I add a duration time to the functions. I have one link called "return" that changes the navigation bar's class back from "after" to "before" and closes every single "page" that opens. When I click this link before the "after" class is added to the navigation bar - before any other link is clicked on - the navigation bar moves as if the "after" class was added and then removed - so it gets smaller and then bigger again. I want the "return" link to not do anything when clicked and the navigation bar is still in the "before" state.

Right now my code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#main_index a").click(function(){
        $("#main_index").addClass("after", 500);
        $("#main_index a").addClass("after_link", 500);
     });
 });

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".return").click(function(){
        $("#main_index").removeClass("after", 500);
        $("#main_index a").removeClass("after_link", 500);
     });
});
```

I've tried adding an if statement to the function using .hasClass so it'll only run if the right class is present but when I do so the functions no longer work. That code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#main_index a").click(function(){
        if(("#main_index").hasClass("before")) {
            $("#main_index").addClass("after", 500);
            $("#main_index a").addClass("after_link", 500);
        }
     });
 });

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".return").click(function(){
        if("#main_index").hasClass("after")) {
            $("#main_index").removeClass("after", 500);
            $("#main_index a").removeClass("after_link", 500);
        }
     });
});
```

I've also tried looking up stuff on here but nothing has worked so far. I know I messed up the code somewhere but I'm kind of a newbie with JQuery and I can't figure out why what I'm doing isn't working like it should. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add jsfiddle here so we can easily know your issue. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't get the jsfiddle to work...i've never used that site before

Answer (score 0):

If is wrong.
And you don't need two ready.
And.... [Addclass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) need only one agrument.

check this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#main_index a").click(function(){
        //if(("#main_index").hasClass("before"))
          if($("#main_index").hasClass("before")) {
            //$("#main_index").addClass("after", 500);
            $("#main_index").addClass("after");
            //$("#main_index a").addClass("after_link", 500);
            $("#main_index a").addClass("after_link");
        }
     });
     $(".return").click(function(){
        //if("#main_index").hasClass("after")) {
          if($("#main_index").hasClass("after")) {
            //$("#main_index").removeClass("after", 500);
            $("#main_index").removeClass("after");
            //$("#main_index a").removeClass("after_link", 500);
            $("#main_index a").removeClass("after_link");
        }
     });
 });
```

Here is [Jsfiddle Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/q7yebkor/)

If you want animation, don't use addClass.
I think,you need to use [animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: I know it works that way - that's what I had before. I want to add a transition to the function so it isn't choppy  (which i found here: http://api.jqueryui.com/removeclass/). it works for the most part, just the the last link acts strangely.

Comment: What is last link?
Is that the same with other elements?
Please tell me your DOM

Answer (score 0):

Obvious problem and solution (can't believe I didn't see it) - since the first function was called with "main_index a" and the second with a link within "main_index" it was performing both functions because it was called by both. Added a class to the other links and called the class for the first function instead of just "main_index a" and fixed the issue.